# Filter tibble for a specific variable but keep non matching rows and fill with NA/NULL

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr

I have this tibble and i want to filter it by all ids of an item, but additionally keep all rows and fill those rows with NA or 0.

```r
library(tibble)
tibble::tibble(item=c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c"), 
               id=c("10","11","12","10","15","16","8","9","12"),
               val=c(25,27,31,24,38,39,12,14,39))

# A tibble: 9 x 3
  item  id      val
  <chr> <chr> <dbl>
1 a     10       25
2 a     11       27
3 a     12       31
4 b     10       24
5 b     15       38
6 b     16       39
7 c     8        12
8 c     9        14
9 c     12       39
```

For example I want to filter all ids of item a (i.e. `10, 11, 12`) and my desired tibble would look like this where I keep all non matching rows and fill `<chr>` with `NA` and `<dbl>` with `0`.

```r
# A tibble: 9 x 3
  item  id      val
  <chr> <chr> <dbl>
1 a     10       25
2 a     11       27
3 a     12       31
4 b     10       24
5 b     NA        0
6 b     NA        0
7 c     NA        0
8 c     NA        0
9 c     12       39
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `replace` or `ifelse` -

```
library(dplyr)

keep <- c(10, 11, 12)

df %>%
  mutate(val = replace(val, !id %in% keep, 0), 
         id = replace(id, !id %in% keep, NA))

#  item  id      val
#  <chr> <chr> <dbl>
#1 a     10       25
#2 a     11       27
#3 a     12       31
#4 b     10       24
#5 b     NA        0
#6 b     NA        0
#7 c     NA        0
#8 c     NA        0
#9 c     12       39
```

---

If you have many columns you may use `across` -

```
df %>%
  mutate(across(c(where(is.character), -item), ~replace(., !id %in% keep, NA)), 
         across(where(is.numeric), ~replace(., !id %in% keep, 0)))
```